# vueJS internal PHP API request not returning JSON

Tags: php, vue.js, axios

I'm using vueJS with node.
I'm trying to make a very simple API request on a internal PHP file (test.php).
The test.php file that is requested is very simple:

```
<?php
    header("Content-Type: application/json");
    $data= ['a', 'b'];
    echo json_encode($data);
```

And here is my request in js :

```
axios.get("../API/test.php")
    .then(response => alert(response.data))
```

Problem is : the response is not JSON, it is the php page code itself :
[image: test.php response in chrome network]

[image: The response]

Here is what I have tested :

- With using fetch and not axios, the result is the same.
- I have tested it on a simple html page with `<script>` that makes a fetch request on the test.php, and it works well..
- Even if the two scripts are on the same server, I added

  ```
   header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
  ```

  in the test.php script, same result (as expected).
- Fetching an external API, it works well (I receive JSON).
- Build the app, it works.

So I presume that the trouble may come from using node?

There is surely something I do wrong, but I don't know what.
I have tried all the solutions I found on Stack Overflow and Google, so I require your help.

Comment: Sounds like you don’t have your server setup up to parse files with the `.php` extension _as PHP_ to begin with …?

Comment: It's possible, I begin with node , webpack, etc..
Here I 'm on the basic installation of vueJS with vue CLI, that I think make a basic configuration that it meant to work with this style of process.
How can I check if my server is setup to parse .php files ?

Comment: Well, you basically _did_ check that already … by making an HTTP request, and seeing what the response was.